# `hub` pull-request for organization repository

Tags: git, github

I want to create a pull request for git from the command line using [`hub`](http://hub.github.com/).  I have a clone of a repository belonging to an organization.  The repository is using git flow, so I want to create a pull request for the `develop` branch.  I have already pushed my feature branch to the organization's repository.

All of the following give me:

> Error creating pull request: Unprocessable Entity (HTTP 422)
>   Missing field: "head_sha"
>   Missing field: "base_sha"
>   No commits between Organization:branch and user:feature-branch

```
git pull-request
git pull-request -b develop
git pull-request -b Organization/Repo/develop
git pull-request -b Repo/develop
git pull-request -b origin/develop
```

I also tried using `-b Organization:Repo:develop`, but that returns a 500 error.  `-b Repo:develop` returns a 404.

How can I create a pull request via `hub`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
git pull-request -b org:master -h org:feature
```

---

Gift wrapped for `.bashrc`

```
function pull_request() {
  BASE="${1:-master}"
  HEAD=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
  ORG=org
  hub pull-request -b ${ORG}:${BASE} -h ${ORG}:${HEAD}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `git request-pull origin/master develop`?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: 1. It provides a possible solution.
2. Unable to comment yet.
3. Best alternative. But thanks for trying to help.